# Is overloading += efficient processing?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I have some code where I first form  `trains` (custom type `Trains` that contains an array of custom type `Train`). I then wish to add some data records to each object in the array that will be used later. Instead of writing a method I overloaded the operator `+`. I know this isn't necessarily the intended purpose for using such an operator overload but I liked the way the code looked!

Anyway now I'm back to feeling sensible and writing a method to do the same task. But its brought an important question to me. What's the difference between the following ways to achieve the same-ish result?

**Overloading Approach**

```
//Add Maintenance History Data (another custom type for storing such data records) to trains
trains += history;

public static Trains operator +(Trains txs, History[] hist)
{
     foreach (Train t in txs)
     {
          t.AddHist(hist.First(x => x.ID == t.ID));
     }
     return txs;

}
```

**Member Approach**

```
trains.AddHist(history);

public void AddHistory(History[] hist)
{
      foreach (Train t in Txs)
      {
          t.AddHist(hist.First(x => x.ID == t.ID));
      }

}
```

I guess that there is a cost for assignment in the overload approach and therefore should stick to the member based approach?

Comment: The first approach seems to be *far less readable*: you are adding arithmetically or concat (`+` *operator*) *train* and a *history* (apples and oranges).

Comment: Yes I have realised this in the end. It just made me wonder more about the background.

Comment: There is a very subtle distinction between the two, you do reassign the *trains* variable when you use the operator.  The odds that you can see the cost of that back are zero, only the reader of your code is going to lose ten minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no specific additional runtime cost there - they are both just methods, although static-based vs instance-based, but that's a tiny tiny difference that will be dwarfed by everything else happening. The bigger issue is the cost of *code clarity* - is it obvious that a `+` operator exists, and has this effect? Also, it means you can't make the method `virtual` for polymorphism.

I'd probably recommend the `AddHistory` method *simply because it is clearer*.

If you are looking to minimize runtime cost, you should:

- avoid LINQ if it involves a capture (it doesn't here, but I'm not sure that the code makes sense, either; if it is actually `hist.First(x => x.ID == t.ID)` then that is involving captures; if the array `hist` is *small*, I'd probably just do a flat `for` loop each time to find the item; if it is *large* I'd build an index *outside* of the `foreach`, probably via `var index = hist.ToDictionary(x => x.Id);`
- look to use `AddRange` etc when possible
- make sure that the `Equals` usage isn't boxing etc - I suspect that `hist.ID == t.ID` would be clearer and more efficient

Comment: ID is in fact a type with `char` and `int`. I've overloaded `Equals`, and `==` and `!=`. I thought they did the same thing. `==` is definitely clearer, but why more efficient?

Comment: I fear I may be overusing LINQ too...hist most likely to be around 100-200 long

Comment: @gwizardry in your case, then, it probably won't be any more efficient - but: there are cases where people have a *value type*, and override the `Equals(Object)` method, but **do not** add an `Equals(SpecificType)` overload. Without this, the runtime will be forced to box the value-type in order to call the method. Worse, if the `Equals(Object)` method *isn't* *overridden*, then it will have to box *both* values. The `==` operator tends to be a: clearer, and b: more reliable in terms of having the correct types.

Comment: @gwizardry for 100-200 I'd be tempted to index to a dictionary first, but: profile it in your scenario. Note that if you're using a dictionary keyed by a custom type (your composite `char` / `int`), then it is very important that you override `GetHashCode` correctly - otherwise *it won't work* as a dictionary key

Comment: For the Equals, I have implemented both methods, with the expected type and with Object, in which case I assume the compiler will choose the one which isn't boxing?

Comment: @gwizardry yes, it would indeed choose the correct one; so that just leaves me with "== is prettier" :)

Comment: ok, yes you answered that one. I've written `(IDnum*((int)IDchar)+1).GetHashCode();` to override the `GetHashCode` where `IDnum` and `IDchar` are the two properties of `ID`. I now realise this is a mistake since could lead to the same number.